# How to Convert a Path with Special Characters to work in a Package

Tags: python, string

I'm able to get some information from a website with Python and BeautifulSoup.
However I get an error when I have a path with a special character.

In the Italian language we have some special characters such as à, è, ì, ò and ù.
If I manually set a, e, i, o and u parsing works.
However if I use BeautifulSoup and parse it automatically I get an error.
Do you know how can I convert these characters into simple vowels?

I put the following settings at the beginning of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Are you looking [to strip diacritics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/364696)? The various accent marks you're talking about are diacritics, it's just unclear if that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package `unidecode`. I've given a code sample below on how to use this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode as ud
italian_string = "L'italiano è classificato al 21º"
ud(italian_string)
```

The last line returns:

```
=> "L'italiano e classificato al 21o"
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I do web scraping. Lecter è was returned in this way: "Ã©". If I use your system that characters will become "A(c)"

Comment: Work perfectly on this: https://repl.it/languages/python3 . What is the string encoded as?

Comment: If you get `"Ã©"` instead of `"è"`, your data is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @cco So what I have to use instead?

Comment: Please put up a complete example of what you're trying to do - when you say 'path', do you mean the path to a file, a path to an element in the document, or the trailing components of a URL?  each of these would have a different answer (and some could have more than one).  Showing what you've tried and what you want to do will be a big help.